# fatal error: call to undefined function validate_ip() in function.php

Tags: php

```
            // check for shared internet/ISP IP
            if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
                return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
            }

            // check for IPs passing through proxies
            if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
                // check if multiple ips exist in var
                if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], ',') !== false) {
                    $iplist = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
                    foreach ($iplist as $ip) {
                        if (validate_ip($ip))
                            return $ip;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
                        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
                }
            }
            if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
                return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
            if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP']))
                return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP'];
            if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
                return $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']) && validate_ip($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
                return $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];

            // return unreliable ip since all else failed
            return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }

        $url = "http://ipinfo.io/".get_ip_address()."/json";

        $json = file_get_contents($url);

        $obj = json_decode($json);
```

Please check this http://screencast.com/t/E9mlGvUt8J

Comment: Where is the function with name `validate_ip`?

Comment: quite sure `validate_ip` is not a standard php function which means either you created it or it's apart of the framework which you have failed to mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have validate_ip() function.
To validate IP adress in php you can use this:
`filter_var($ip_a, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)`